# Current Time(PHP) + SQL time = AS SQL Timestamp

Tags: php, sql, time, timestamp

I have 2 tables in my SQL Database. One is called `dungeons` and the other one is called `dungeonruns`.

In the `dungeons` table there is one row called `time` it's the SQL time format 00:00:00. In the `dungeonruns` table is a row called `stoptime` which is in the timestamp format 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I want my PHP script to get the time from `dungeons`, add it to the current time and then save it in the `stoptime` row.

This is what I have tried:

```
$stoptime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') + $time;
//$time is the time from the DB and its the 00:00:00 format.
```

Comment: what part do you have problem? The add time or the saving to db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqlDateTime = '2015-09-01 00:00:00';
$timeToAdd     = '12:30:00';

$timeParts      = explode(':', $timeToAdd);
$intervalString = sprintf('PT%dH%dM%dS', $timeParts[0], $timeParts[1], $timeParts[2]);
$stopTime       = (new DateTime($mysqlDateTime))->add(new DateInterval($intervalString))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/431920)

Basically, to add that time to that datetime value you need to turn it into a DateInterval which you can then add to a DateTime object.